# why Airflow PythonOperator task failed but return code is 0?

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

i have a Airflow DAG which runs with PythonOperator, I wonder why my task executes failed but exit with a return code 0?

Executed failed with return code zero misled me to regard the task as executes successfully.

You can see below job logs or attachment picture, could anyone explain why this would happen and advise how to avoid this?

**Task instance logs:**

> [2019-11-15 22:45:23,633] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 736: Subtask http_request_send_push 2019-11-15 22:45:23,632 - 10688 -    ERROR -   74 - http_request_send_push:http_request_send_push service trigger-resend-push error::
>
> [2019-11-15 22:45:23,633] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO -
>
> [2019-11-15 22:45:23,632] {notification.py:74} ERROR - http_request_send_push:http_request_send_push service trigger-resend-push error::
>
> [2019-11-15 22:45:23,633] {python_operator.py:114} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
>
> [2019-11-15 22:45:25,251] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO -
>
> [2019-11-15 22:45:25,250] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 0

**Task instance log screenshot:**

[image]

**DAG Tree view screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: This depends on what you are running using the PythonOperator. Can you paste that please?

Comment: Suppose the log and screenshot i uploaded had already describe the problem clearly, i will paste the scripts and any suggests would be appreciate.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, `PythonOperator` is just an operator that will execute a python function. If there are any errors and you want the task to `failed` state then you need to raise an Exception inside your python callable function. In below example code, see `fourth_task`.

An alternative to this is to use `ShortCircuitOperator`. 
Below is the description from the [Apache Airflow API reference guide](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator):

> It evaluates a condition and **short-circuits** the workflow if the condition is False. Any downstream tasks are marked with a state of “skipped”. If the condition is True, downstream tasks proceed as normal.

See the below sample code which explains the difference between `PythonOperator` and `ShortCircuitOperator`. Also shows how to raise Exception and change the task to `failed` state.

```py
def first_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("first_task")


def second_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("second_task")
    return True


def third_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("third_task")
    return False


def fourth_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("fourth_task")
    raise Exception()


def fifth_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("fifth_task")
    return True


def sixth_task(**kwargs):
    logging.info("sixth_task")
    return False

first_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='first_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=first_task,
    dag=dag)
first_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='first_task_successor', dag=dag)
first_task_successor.set_upstream(first_task)


second_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='second_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=second_task,
    dag=dag)
second_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='second_task_successor', dag=dag)
second_task_successor.set_upstream(second_task)


third_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='third_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=third_task,
    dag=dag)
third_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='third_task_successor', dag=dag)
third_task_successor.set_upstream(third_task)


fourth_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fourth_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=fourth_task,
    dag=dag)
fourth_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='fourth_task_successor', dag=dag)
fourth_task_successor.set_upstream(fourth_task)


fifth_task = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='fifth_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=fifth_task,
    dag=dag)
fifth_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='fifth_task_successor', dag=dag)
fifth_task_successor.set_upstream(fifth_task)

sixth_task = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='sixth_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=sixth_task,
    dag=dag)
sixth_task_successor = DummyOperator(task_id='sixth_task_successor', dag=dag)
sixth_task_successor.set_upstream(sixth_task)
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i've tried the way you suggest.After add "raise Exception()", successor task didn't run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@kaxil The codes are as below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import inspect
import urllib.request
import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['test@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='airflow_so',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=args,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=5),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(seconds=10)
)

def http_request_send_push(ds, **kwargs):
    endpoint='http://10.19.54.110:8080/v1/trigger-scheduled-push'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

    endpoint='http://10.19.54.110:8080/v1/trigger-scheduled-repush'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

http_request_send_push = PythonOperator(
    task_id='http_request_send_push',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=http_request_send_push,
    dag=dag
)


def http_request_send_sms(ds, **kwargs):
    endpoint='http://10.19.54.134:8080/v1/scheduleSendSms'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

    endpoint='http://10.19.54.134:8080/v1/scheduleReSendSms'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

http_request_send_sms = PythonOperator(
    task_id='http_request_send_sms',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=http_request_send_sms,
    dag=dag
)


def http_request_send_email(ds, **kwargs):
    endpoint='http://10.19.54.138:8080/v1/scheduleSendEmail'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

    endpoint='http://10.19.54.138:8080/v1/scheduleReSendEmail'
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(e),
                 e)
    else:
        req = response.read()
        print('%s:%s:%s',
                 inspect.stack()[0][3],
                 type(req),
                 req)

http_request_send_email = PythonOperator(
    task_id='http_request_send_email',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=http_request_send_email,
    dag=dag
)

http_request_send_push >> http_request_send_sms >> http_request_send_email

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```